# Android master screen for application

Tags: android, iframe

I'm trying to implement an Android application with something like a master page, a screen with the main header, some buttons, and logo and stuff, and a client area with the business logic for each screen.

I know this is doable in web by using something like iFrames, is this doable in Android?

Answer (score 0):

A "page" in Android is called an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

With new newest APIs (introduced in API level 11, which is Android 3.0), you've got the [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) framework to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: But that would mean that my app will no longer function under older Android versions right?

Comment: I know :( There is something called Android compatibility package, which allow you to use newest features even when you're targetting older versions. I haven't used it, but you can check it out. It uses Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a master screen having buttons.On clicking these buttons will lead to other screens.If this is what you want to do then you can use Activity in android.You can even pass data within activity.Below are some links which can help you to achieve this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html